# how to get only active sheet name from excel file using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to get only active sheet name from excel file using c#,but now i am getting all the sheet names,how can i get only active sheet name from excel using c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the ActiveSheet property to get the name out of it

See link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activesheet

e.g.

```
WorkSheet sheet = (WorkSheet)_application.activesheet;

string name = sheet.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use NugetPackage Library NPOI (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi).
You can retrieve lots of useful information about Excel files (XLSX or XLS). Including the active worksheet when the workbook was saved (`ActiveSheetIndex` property).
It has the advantage of not relying on Microsoft Interpot API (not requiring Excel to be installed).
You may try this:

`using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
 using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
 using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;`

...

```
//Stream
FileStream arquivoXLSX = new FileStream(XLSXWorkbokPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//Workbook Data from XML
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(XLSXWorkbokPath);

//Active Worksheet Index
var ActWsIndex = workbook.ActiveSheetIndex;
//Active Worksheet Name
var ActWsName = workbook.GetSheetName(ActWsIndex);
```

I hope it helps.