# UserInput data onto chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I want to lay the users input values onto the scatter chart. I've managed to get it to work using "Sheet1" in the code, however in reality the sheet tabs are going to vary with numbers etc.

What can I change within this code to make look at the active sheet?

```vb
'Add UserInput Data to Chart

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""min"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=sheet1!$C$3,sheet1!$C$193"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=sheet1!$E$3,sheet1!$E$3"

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""max"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=sheet1!$C$3,sheet1!$C$193"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "=sheet1!$F$3,sheet1!$F$3"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607722/how-to-get-only-active-sheet-name-from-excel-file-using-c

Comment: This looks like VB.Net, not C#.

Comment: I think it could also be VB6 / VBA, but we would need @Wales to weigh in

Comment: If you are working with `Excel` please update your tags accordingly... Also `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` returns a `Series` object, you are not assigning this to any variable, what do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: Type of  `FullSeriesCollection(3).Values` and `FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues` is an `Array` or `Range`, not a `String`.  See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.values